# Sending Multiple messages got delayed Quickblox IOS

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

While sending multiple messages between users got delayed.

i am using quickblox internal method for sending message.

```
[dialog sendMessage:message completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) 
{

}];
```

Sending multiple messages are delayed so this does not seem good and it does not seem like chatting real time.

By multiple i mean sending messages frequently to other users.

Comment: Please provide us logs for both devices, where you are sending messages, and where you are receiving them. Also please specify your SDK version. You can also contact Quickblox SDK developers on their github repository by creating an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Plan under which you are using in Quickblox. By default Starter plan available with more limitations.